# Can a GIF be added to a tab bar item in swift

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I want to display a GIF in the iOS tab bar item instead of a tab bar image.
I have gone through the Apple Docs, which says the customization is not possible.

Is there any way this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way, which as you state is *not* documented and may break somewhere in the future. You can get the uiviews contained into the UITabBar as follow:

var tabBarButtons:[UIControl] { myTabBar.subviews.compactMap({$0 as? UIControl}) }

that returns the array of UIControl in the order from left to right, each one representing the actual tab bar items. 
(by instance, tabBarButtons.count == myTabBar.items.count)

once got that, you can eventually add to your buttons an UIImageView with layouts, which finally renders your animated image, or whatever else you think fits the need

**Note**: as not officially supported, hidden tab bar items which are under “more” could not be affected. I can’t tell you right now how it will behave if you have more than let’s say 5 items in the tab bar

Hope that helps

Comment: I have tried this in the past and works till iOS 12. Need some solution that works on iOS 13 as well. Will apple allow such customization?

Comment: I’ve done it and run on simulator on iOS 13.3, and was working fine, still as experimental. Can’t tell if they will change anything in the future, but we can still assume that tab bar and items are controls, so they should be part of the view hierarchy, so I assume they will be always reachable by scanning the subviews